# MVC tab is not present in Intellij IDEA Spring plugin for Spring Boot project

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.6 Gradle project, simple demo application.
I would like to see my request mappings and controllers in Spring plugin. But it doesn't show me MVC tab at all. My controller is presented in beans tab as expected as well as in endpoints tab while running the application.

[image]

If I configure Spring Data in my project it starts to appear Data tab in Spring plugin as expected.
Also, MVC tab works well with Spring MVC project.

I have played with Spring Facets configuration but it doesn't give me any positive results.

Here is my IDEA info:

> IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.2 Build #IU-172.3757.29, built on August 8, 2017
>   Licensed to IntelliJ IDEA Evaluator Expiration date: August 25, 2017
>   JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b10 x86_64 JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by
>   JetBrains s.r.o Mac OS X 10.12.6

Can you please help me to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

This feature is currently in development for 2017.3, please watch https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132738 for progress.